# System getting crashed whenever i try to open fabric plugin in eclipse

Tags: twitter-fabric

Steps i performed:

```
Install Fabric plug-in in eclipse,
Restart Eclipse,
Click on Fabric icon from menu bar at the top of the eclipse.
I logged in,
After that ubuntu get crashed.
After that whenever I Click on Fabric icon from menu bar system gets crashed
```

OS version - Ubuntu 15.04
eclipse version - Luna (4.4.2)

Comment: When I try to open the Fabric plugin Eclipse crashes... Could be a similar issue